# Issue with header(Location)

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

```
if ($count == 1){ //if username + pass is correct
    $cookie_value = $user;
    setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (180), "/");
    header("Location: personal.php");
}else{ //wrong info
    echo "Gebruikersnaam of passwoord is niet juist!";
}
}else if (isset($_POST['register'])){
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];
    $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt");
    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'users' ( username, password) VALUES ($user', '$phash')'; ";
    $result = myqli_query($conn, $sql);
}
?>
```

Ok so at when i try to press register it doesn't bring me to personal.php but it just loads the same thing again. (logreg.php, this code file)

If anyone see why the header doesn't work let me know!

EDIT: the problem now is that it can't even execute past the Isset. Now it doesn't even reach anything. code:

```
if (isset($_POST['login']))
{
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt"); //password: not visible 

    $sql = "SELECT 'username' FROM 'users' WHERE username ='$user' AND password='$phash'; "; //fetching database

    $result = myqli_query($conn, $sql); //check if login is right
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); 

    if ($count == 1) //if username + pass is ok
    {
        $cookie_value = $user;
            setcookie($cookie_name, $cookie_value, time() + (180), "/");
        echo '<a href="personal.php">Continue</a>';
    }
    else 
    {
        echo "username or password is incorrect";
    }
}
else if (isset($_POST['register']))
{
    $user = $_POST['username'];
    $pass = $_POST['password'];

    $phash = sha1(sha1($pass."salt")."salt");

    $sql = "INSERT INTO 'users' ( username, password) VALUES ($user', '$phash')'; ";

    $result = myqli_query($conn, $sql);

}
?>
```

Comment: Is anything being echo'd prior to the call to `header`? You can't do a header redirect if any of the page has already been sent to the client.

Comment: you havent given header redirection when  register is set

Comment: You have an else if but I don't see the opening if. Did you miss some pieces of code? Did you notice that you have an else and after that an else if?

Comment: Use `$_SESSION` instead of cookies for storing user id

Comment: @user3284463 Aren't session variables just an abstraction over cookies?

Comment: @Carcigenicate Yes, just that they are more easy to secure since they are stored on server side and not client side. Session values are hidden and can't be manipulated while cookies can

Answer (score 1):

add

```
exit();
```

after

```
header("Location: personal.php");
```

And will work